# Why do need the tag sentience if we already have artificial-consciousness and emotional-intelligence?

Tags: discussion, tags

I believe that the tag [sentience](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentience) is not necessary given that we already have [artificial-consciousness](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-consciousness) and [emotional-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-intelligence). A sentient AI is an an AI that perceives or feels (according to the dictionary definition of "sentient"), so all questions about sentient AI fall either under [emotional-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-intelligence) (or [artificial-consciousness](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-consciousness)), so I suggest it should be merged with [emotional-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-intelligence).

Answer (score 1):

- Sentience can refer to biological agents, so has a broader scope.

We sometimes discuss intelligence in general, as a concept underlying AI, and do too with sentience.

- Emotional intelligence seems to be an informal term related to a specific kind of decision making

I don't see much relation to sentience in general, except that we regard only sentient beings as having emotions in the conventional sense.

Comment: I realized later that emotional intelligence is more about having control of your own emotions. However, I would say that, in general, we should not introduce a tag if the expression is not widely known or standard. I am not sure if sentience is the most common expression to refer to AIs that have emotions. Maybe it is ok to have the tag sentience.

Comment: I think there's a more common term to refer to methods that understand or mimic feelings. It's [_affective computing_ or _artificial emotional intelligence_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affective_computing), so maybe emotional intelligence already covers the tag sentience. Therefore, I would say, we don't need the tag sentience because emotional intelligence (EI) or AEI already covers everything related to sentient AI and it is a more common term.